# OrderByDescending missing criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have an list in which new integers are being added while the code is running and after this i want to use the linq function "OrderByDescending" but my list seem's to not contain the criteria I'm looking for.My question is how do i add it because the following code is not doing the work..

```
List<int> Arr = new List<int>();
Power = 5;
current = 1;
Arr.Add(current);
Arr.Add(Power);
Arr.OrderByDescending(p => p.current).ThenByDescending(p => p.power).First();
```

I get http://prntscr.com/98pumi

Comment: This doesn't compile since the objects in your list (`int`s) do not have a property or field named `current` or `power`.

Comment: how do i add it than ?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to actually achieve here... what do you expect `OrderByDescending(p => p.current)` to do on a sequence of integers?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how the OrderBy expressions work. The lamda expression needs to be the name of a property of the object in the list being sorted. Sorting a list of Integers can only be done ascending or descending, not both at the same time...

Comment: current and Power are being changed during the code runtime the order by should be at the end of it but i removed most of it because it's repetitive and each time power or current change's it get's added to the list Arr and at the end i want to check the highest current + the highest power at the same time

Comment: there's only descending order in my code right ?

Comment: You are creating a List of Integers and not a custom class. In the brackets where your lambda expression is (`p => p.current`), a new variable p is created of type `int` and integers do not have a property "current" or "power". Create a custom class (eg.: `class MyClass`) that define these properties and create a `List<MyClass>`.

Comment: If i use class how to change the variable's value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My crystal ball told me you may need something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Device> list = new List<Device>(){
                new Device(){Power = 3,Current =2}
                , new Device(){Power = 2, Current = 2}
                , new Device(){Power = 1, Current = 3}
            };

            var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(d=>d.Current).ThenByDescending(d=>d.Power);

            foreach (var d in sorted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current {0}, Power {1}",d.Current,d.Power);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Device
    {
        public int Power {get;set;}
        public int Current { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Basically, create a class to hold those properties you are trying to sort.